# Nancy & forms authentication: How to invalidate all sessions of a logged in authenticated user?

Tags: session, nancy

I am using [Nancy Web Framework](http://nancyfx.org/) and [forms authentication](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Forms%20Authentication).

How do I programmatically invalidate all sessions of a logged in authenticated user?

Logging out the

```
Context.CurrentUser
```

with

```
MyNancyModule.Logout()
```

just invalidates one session,
if the user is logged in from (e.g.) another browser,
this session is still valid.

**That is a good thing**, but I want to invalidate all sessions after the user changed her/his password.

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is change the `GUID` identifier on the user record that your `UserMapper` maps to from the session cookie - that will automatically invalidate every single session out there for that user, forcing them to log back in and get a new cookie.